# One shared selector between multiple classes

Tags: sass

How to apply the same focus state to multiple different classes?

Problem:

```
.btn {
 &.error {
   border-color: red;
 }

 &.primary {
   border-color: green;
 }

 &:focus {
   border-color: blue; 
   // this is not applied but i don't want to 
   // declare the same style to both classes 
 }
}
```

I understand this would be one option, but it is also not the prettiest option as i need to list them separately here

```
.btn {
 &.error {
   border-color: red;
 }

 &.primary {
   border-color: green;
 }

 &.primary:focus, &.error:focus {
   border-color: blue; 
 }
}
```

Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Using `&` again in the nested rule is a good way for your purpose.

```
.btn {
    &.error {
        border-color: red;
    }
    
    &.primary {
        border-color: green;
    }
    
    &.primary, &.error {
        &:focus{
            border-color: blue; 
        }
    }
}
```